# Google form won't let submit file in iframe

Tags: jquery, google-forms

I wanted to put Google form in my .PHP page with iframe. All works fine until I add a file upload in G form. The form appears in an iframe but when I click Add file then I get a blank screen. After checking settings in Google form, I notice that EMBED HTML has been disabled with the message

> This form cannot be embedded because it makes use of File Upload questions

This is the iframe I use:

```
<p><a class='iframe' href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/form_ID/viewform">Test iFRAME</a></p>
```

and I use a colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ jQuery for popup screen (where my form need to be)

This is the script for jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
    $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
    $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
    $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
    $(".ajax").colorbox();
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
    $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
    $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                    onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                    onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                    onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                    onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                    onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });

    $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
    $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none', retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

    // Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
    $("#click").click(function() {   
        $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I try to search for the problem, but cannot find a solution, I did find some similar question but did not find this example of the problem.